# Hard drive raid compadibility

Tags: raid, raid-1

Given that I have a RAID 1 array of two 2TB hard disks 3Gb/s @ 5400rpm could one of the drives be switched out for a 2TB 6Gb/s @ 7200 rpm?

How do you know if two drives will be compatible in a RAID array?

Further Details:
Asus M49A89TD Mobo with built-in hybrid raid technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could one of the drives be switched out for a 2TB 6Gb/s @ 7200 rpm?

Short: Yes, without problem.

Long: **Most** RAID levels RAID does not need synchronised spindles. (Exeption: RAID levels 3 and 4, which nobody uses. See [this link for commonly used RAID levels](http://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them) and [this link to wikipedia for RAID level 3 (byte level striping) and RAID level 4 (block level striping)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_4)

> How do you know if two drives will be compatible in a RAID array?

If the replaced drive is equal in size, or larger than the drive it replaces it just works.  If it is smaller then you have to do some work.

Note that 2TB drives are usually drive of slightly less than 2TB, rounded up by marketing. There is about a 50% chance that one one of your drives is smaller. Hopefully it is not the new one.